# Upload file control not showing any file in the code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a very simple application. I am trying to upload the file using File upload control of ASP.net. Below is my entire .cs code and .aspx code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestFileUpload1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
                {
                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), uploadedFile.FileName));
                    //listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My .aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestFileUpload1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test web site</title>
       <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

  <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
              <div>
             <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />  
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />  
             <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />  
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

whenever I try to upload a file, I get "False" for  UploadImages.HasFiles.
Above is full working example.
As soon as I remove one of these script tags :

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

  <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

my code starts working and I get "true" for UploadImages.HasFiles when I try to upload a file.

I am using .net framework 4.7.2

I need to keep these two script tags in my code because of the GUI and this is an old application where these tags are used in all the pages.

I also tried to wrap the control in a update panel and that didn't work either. below is the changed .aspx page. although, I want my original code to work. I don't want to use ajax, but I just tried to use it because it is suggested as one of the solution

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestFileUpload1.WebForm1" %>
<%--<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="asp"%>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test web site</title>
       <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

  <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
              <div>
                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                       <Triggers>
                           <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadedFile" />
                        </Triggers>
                      
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
              <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
             <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />  
                      
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the image of false value that I am getting in code behind:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do is put data-ajax ="false" in form tag and that fixed the issue.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server" data-ajax ="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a update panel and wrap your controls inside it. Then add the button controlID as a trigger (be sure its a PostBackTrigger) to the update panel. To test be sure to put a break point on the uploadFile_Click event so you can step through and see the values..

```
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"     UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSignaureOfRequestor" />
</Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
       <table>
            <tr>  <td class="tdText" colspan="4">
           <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="50%" />
                    </td>
                            </tr>
<tr>
    <td> <asp:Button ID="btnSignaureOfRequestor" runat="server"  Text="Submit Request" Visible="true" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are  you sure you want to continue?');" OnClick="btnSignaureOfRequestor_Click" />
                               </td>
   </tr>                                  
                     </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work., I pasted the updated .aspx file above and that is also returning false for hasfiles.

Comment: Don't use AsyncPostBackTrigger  use PostBackTrigger, only PostBackTrigger will work

Comment: I tried using postBackTriggers and I still get false in code behind. I pasted the picture of code behind too. Above is a full working example. You can copy and paste above code in any asp.net web form and you can replicate the issue.

Comment: Try placing the button inside the content template of the updatepanel

Comment: when I did this, I start getting an error: A control with ID 'uploadedFile' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: where did you put the button next to the fileupload? can you post your code

Comment: Your code should work, only thing that looks weird is your ajaxtoolkit reference, especially the tagprefix asp which could be getting things confused on the page.    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="asp"%> instead try using a different tag prefix, e.g. <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit"%>   Or remove the reference doesn't look like you are using it.

Comment: I tried changing to ajaxToolKit. still not working. I also removed the ajaxcontroltoolkit register assembly. Still the code behind is giving me false for hasfiles.

Comment: I pasted my entire code in my post. My code behind is same. .aspx file is pasted down below. I moved the button outside of the contentTemplate because of the error that I was getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218401/discussion-between-anjali-and-jobesk).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Remove allow multiple and add update mode conditional (see confirm case/syntax of these changes as I'm just writing it in notepad).

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
          <div>
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" />&nbsp;
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                   <Triggers>
                       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadedFile" />
                    </Triggers>                   
                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
 
         <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />  
                  
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this code wont help me because my requirement is that customer can select multiple files. I also tried the code that you gave me above and it didnt work. I am still getting false for hasFiles

Comment: Code works on my side, not sure why not working for you... There are many ways to approach the requirement. Notate if multiple files to have user zip them up. Or you could add multiple file uploads to the page. You can also build a separate page with file uploads and open it up in a modal dialog.